# Sharing Cookies Between Two ASP.NET Core Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using [WsFederation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation) in two separate ASP.NET Core projects.

Each project has the following in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddWsFederation(options =>
{
    options.Wtrealm = Configuration["Wtrealm"];
    options.MetadataAddress = "http://example.com/metadata.xml";
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MySharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".dev.example.com";
});
```

I load project #1 in the browser and I get my cookie:

[image]

I then navigate to project #2 on the same sub domain. However, project #2 doesn't recognize `MySharedCookie` and re-authenticates. I get a new cookie with the same name but a different value:

[image]

Is what I'm trying to do possible in ASP.NET Core? Is there a way in ASP.NET Core I can share project #1's cookie with project #2?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) can help?

Comment: They must also share their data protection keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented at [Sharing cookies among apps with ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation). There is also a [Cookie Sharing App Sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/cookie-sharing/sample/) available.

In order to share cookies, you create a `DataProtectionProvider` in each app and using a common/shared set of keys between the apps.

```
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Domain = "example.com";
    options.DataProtectionProvider =
        DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo("path-tokeys"));
});
```

Comment: Or better yet, configure the data protection service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x#persistkeystofilesystem services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));