# Strange Cookie name and content in .net core

Tags: http, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a brand new asp.net Core 3 web app that is supposed to work with an existing asp.net web app. The asp.net app is supposed to pass on some authentication information and metadata to the asp.netCore app but it shows an incorrect value for the name and content of one of the cookies!

The Asp.Net app creates two cookies, one with authentication token and one with some metadata about the user.  as described below:

**Cookie 1**

```
name: MyCompanyAuth 
value: [string of random stuff, ie Authentication Token]
SameSite: (Nothing)
```

**Cookie 2**

```
name: MyCompanyUser 
value: Username=JohnDoe&Fullname=John Doe&ClientID=123456
SameSite: None

(expiry, domain, path, httpOnly, and Secure are the same.)
```

The first cookie is picked up perfectly by the asp.net core app. However, it cannot find the second cookie. But when I open the `context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies` collection it has this other cookie:

```
name: Doe&ClientID=
value: 123456
```

In the browser When I open up the dev tools and check the cookies everything seems to be fine but the webserver picks this weirdly. Also, I checked the code in the main app (asp.net one which creates the cookies) and it does not set SameSite for any of these at all.

---

**Update:**

`context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]` has the correct and complete contents, So either:

1) There is a bug in Asp.NetCore.MVC where it is converting `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]` to a list of cookies, OR,

2) My call is violating some cookie size limitations. (but how can this be the case because the very end of the information is still in there!)

Comment: Check the configurations that documented at [Sharing cookies among apps with ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) , you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49329480/10201850) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into documentation I noticed that `value: Username=JohnDoe&Fullname=John Doe&ClientID=123456` is not standard (although asp.net allows it) and .net core does not allow it anymore!