# How to make general cookie authentication for 2 asp.net core apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

I have 2 asp.net core webapis under 1 subdomain, and I'm going to add cookie authentication to one of them based on first api, but it doesn't working. It can't parse cookies from other one. I read some articles about this point, but is didn't help. One of them

1. [Sharing Cookies Between Two ASP.NET Core Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328660/sharing-cookies-between-two-asp-net-core-applications)
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Info about APIs

1. Using .NET 6, cookie authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity, authentication works fine

   ```
   builder.Services.AddIdentity<User.Repository.Entities.User, 
   IdentityRole>(options =>
   {
       options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
       options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
   })
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

   builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
   {
       options.Cookie.Name = "Custom.Identity";
       options.Cookie.Domain = "custom.com";
       options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
       {
           context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       };
   });
   builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
                   .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\security-keys"))
                   .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

   builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication()
   ```
2. Using asp.net core 3, used jwt token auth before, I want to add cookie auth there without ASP.NET Core Identity; Authentication always fails with cookies from first API

   ```
       services.AddDataProtection()
           .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\security-keys"))
           .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

       services.AddAuthentication(options =>
       {

           options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.Name = "Custom.Identity";
               options.Cookie.Domain = "custom.com";

               options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
               {
                   context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                   return Task.CompletedTask;
               };
           });
   ```

P.S. Records from failed API logs.

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[7]
          Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
```

Anybody knows the possible reason of auth failing?

Comment: Why are you using cookies with a _Web API_? Cookies are only really used within user-facing web-browsers, whereas _Web API_ services are consumed mostly by client-libraries that tend to use signed-requests or bearer-tokens.

Comment: For simple implementing Single Sign On for 2 APIs. Cookies can be shared between 2 subdomains, but tokens can't

Comment: You are mistaken: The current state-of-the-art for Single Sign On using OIDC does not use shared-cookies: it uses [many different grants and flows depending on the client and use-case](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/oauth-openid/#oauth-2-0). Also, cookies sharing `domain=` parameters are _not_ always shared between origins and this decades-old "feature" ([more of a security liability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33851/69237)) will likely be removed in upcoming browser-releases. Finally, "tokens can't be shared between 2 subdomains" is utter nonsense.